# Don't show the DataTemplate of a specific group in a CollectionView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a `CollectionView` with groups of items. Each group has a title. what I would like to do is not to display the `DataTemplate` of the first group, while displaying all the others. I searched but found nothing.

```
int count = 0;
HumorGroup group = null;

public ObservableCollection<HumorGroup> TotHumor { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<HumorGroup>();
foreach (HumorDiary hd in mylist)
       {
           if (hd.Dt.Date.Month != count)
            {                                    
                count = hd.Dt.Date.Month;
                group = new HumorGroup("Group", new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>());
            
                TotHumor.Add(group);
            }
        group.Add(hd);
       }
```

Comment: you need to modify your data source and remove the data you do not want to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a DataTemplateSelector where you can return an empty DataTemplate for your specific case.

See the official documentation on how to create one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

> A DataTemplateSelector can be used to choose a DataTemplate at runtime
> based on the value of a data-bound property. This enables multiple
> DataTemplates to be applied to the same type of object, to customize
> the appearance of particular objects.